# How do you add the "each in" to work in handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Ember is migrating to a [non-context switching](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) `#each` helper. For a compatibility piece I need to do the same from raw handlebars.

However the [trivial attempt fails](http://jsbin.com/dizoyolabi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var f = Handlebars.compile("{{#each numbers}}{{this}}{{/each}}");
console.log(f({numbers: [1,2,3]}));
// works

var f2 = Handlebars.compile("{{#each number in numbers}}{{number}}{{/each}}");
console.log(f2({numbers: [1,2,3]}));
// fails
```

How do I get `{{#each number in numbers}}` to work in raw handlebars 2.0?

**EDIT**

Added a bounty here, for a handlebars extension based off https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/lib/ember_compat_handlebars.js that gives us each.. in support. It is clear its not built into handlebars. It is also clear Ember is able to extend this.

Comment: I think its a bug. Even if we use Em.Handlebars.compile, if give an error 'Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined'

Comment: Ember's precompiled functions expect additional context that isn't provided by just passing in the hash.  It's expecting views, containers, controllers, the works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows how it can be done. But note that it requires the `stringParams` flag at compile time, which changes the way all helpers get called, so this will probably break all the other helpers unless you provide `stringParams` compatible versions of them.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(localName,inKeyword,contextName,options){
  var list = this[contextName];
  var output = "";
  var innerContext = Object.create(this);
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    innerContext[localName] = list[i];
    output += options.fn(innerContext);
  }
  return output;
});

 var f = Handlebars.compile("{{#each number in numbers}}{{number}}{{/each}}", {
  stringParams: true
});

console.log(f({numbers: [1,2,3]}));
```

Comment: @SamSaffron, shouldn't this be the accepted answer? Looks like it was added to your extension on github.

Answer (score 4):

The non-context switching each helper is a helper introduced in Ember, it isn't part of the core handlebars library.  You won't be able to use it with plain ol' handlebars.

Comment: had a chat with wycats and he confirmed this, still we already override it https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/lib/ember_compat_handlebars.js so I just need to figure out what magic I need to add there

Comment: Thats not the entire story given handlebars has non context switching block params on master already as per my answer and working jsbin.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you question correctly, I believe this will work.

```
var hbs = "{{#each this}}{{this}}{{/each}}";
var f3 = Handlebars.compile(hbs);
console.log(f3({numbers: [1,2,3]}));
console.log(f3({numbers: [3,2,1]}));
```

http://jsbin.com/tebayupobu/4/edit

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't need to implement this at all since Handlebars is moving to block parameters for non context switching helpers. Ember is already using block params in 1.10 Beta (you can read about block params in the [release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/08/ember-1-9-0-released.html)).

You can use the latest builds of Handlebars to get the non context switching each with the new block params syntax right now:

```
var f = Handlebars.compile("{{#each numbers}}{{this}}{{/each}}");
console.log(f({numbers: [1,2,3]}));

var f = Handlebars.compile("{{#each numbers as |number|}}{{number}}{{/each}}");
console.log(f({numbers: [1,2,3]}));
```

Console:

```
"123"
"123"
```

Updated [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zumuqaziji/1/edit?html,js,output,console) with the new syntax.